# How to set absolute x coordinate of text in svg?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

I want to align several `<text>` in the same x coordinate in a `<svg>` and
surround the `<text>` with `<rect>`.

I specified `x` attribute of `<text>` to align several `<text>`, and
I got the coordinates of `<text>` with `getBBox()` to determine x position of `<rect>`.
`getBBox().x`, however, is different from the specified `x` in some `<text>`, although `<g>` including `<text>` and `<rect>` was not transformed yet.

Why are they different?
How can I set an absolute x coordinate of `<text>` (e.g. to zero in the following code), and
how can I get the absolute x coordinate of the `<text>`?

I executed the following code on Chrome 59 (64bit) on Windows 10 (64bit).

**Update:**

When I ran the code on Firefox, 
I got the same (expected) x coordinate using `getBBox().x` as the `x` attribute of `<text>`.

Is additional effort needed on Chrome?

```js
const PADDING = 5
const BOX_X = 10

const data = [
  {text: "My"},
  {text: "x"},
  {text: "coordinate"},
  {text: "is"},
  {text: "zero?"}
]

const box = d3.select("svg#svg")
  .selectAll(".text-rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .classed("text-rect", true)

// draw text
const text = box
  .append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .attr("font-family", "Arial")
  .attr("x", 0) // <- I set `x` to zero here
  .attr("y", 0)
  .text((d) => d.text)
  .each(function(d){ d.textBBox = this.getBBox() })

// surround text using coorrdinates from `getBBox()` of `<text>`
box
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", (d) => d.textBBox.x - PADDING)
  .attr("y", (d) => d.textBBox.y - PADDING)
  .attr("width", (d) => d.textBBox.width + 2 * PADDING)
  .attr("height", (d) => d.textBBox.height + 2 * PADDING)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)

// avoid overlap
box
  .each(function(d){ d.bbox = this.getBBox() })
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    let oldY = d.bbox.y
    d.bbox.y = (i==0)? 0 : box.data()[i-1].bbox.y + box.data()[i-1].bbox.height
    return `translate(${BOX_X},${d.bbox.y - oldY})`
  });

// show coordinates
const div = d3.select("div#coordinates")
  .selectAll("p")
  .data(text.data())
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .text((d) => `"${d.text}": (${d.textBBox.x}, ${d.textBBox.y})`)
// I set `x` attribute of `<text>` to zero,
// but `getBBox()` returned a different x coordinate.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>SVG is drawn here</h3>
    <svg id="svg" width="150" height="150"></svg>
    <hr>
    <h3>XY coordinates are shown here</h3>
    <div id="coordinates"></div>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

1. [Results of Chrome and Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlSKM.png)
2. [Results of Different font-size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiAkj.png)

Comment: Sometimes, usually for kerning or serif reasons, a letter may overlap just a little to the left of its actual anchor point. The bounding box reflects that.

Comment: According to the link by Paul LeBeau, the kerning occurs between letters placed side-by-side. Does the kerning occur at the first letter in a line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "side bearing". It's the difference between a characters X position and the left (or right) of the glyph.  For example, rounded characters like an "O" may need to stick out slightly to the left to look optically correct when left aligned with other text above or below.

The following image doesn't illustrate that, but it does show what side bearing is.

[image]

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/TypoFeatures/TextSystemFeatures.html

Comment: An amount of left-side-bearing is different depending on letters, and
letters are placed at `x` of `<text>` using an origin point; hence, the left side of a glyph of a letter does not align.
When I call `getBBox()`, the bounding box of a glyph is returned without the left-side-bearing
and thus, I get different x coordinates. Is this correct?
However, when a bigger `font-size` is specified, `getBBox().x` becomes zero although left-side-bearing becomes bigger.

Comment: No. When you place a character at X, the (left) side bearing of the character may mean that the minX of the bounding box is different from X. If the left side bearing is 0, X and minX should be the same.  If the left side bearing is less than zero, the character will extend to the left of X, and therefore the minX of the bbox will be less than X. And vice-versa if the left side bearing is greater than zero - as is the case for the example character in the illustration.